# File provider used in sending email attachment keeps crashing

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send an email upon button click with an attachment stored in internal storage. I tried following this tutorial in implementing a file provider, however every time I try running the app and pressing the button the app crashes and stops working.

I am lost for why that may be. Below is the relevant code:

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>

        </provider>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

filepaths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <paths>
        <cache-path name="cache" path="/" />
        <files-path name= "files" path="/" />
    </paths>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

MainActivity.java

```
Button emailBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            main = findViewById(R.id.main);//email form button
            emailBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Bitmap b = Screenshot.takescreenshotOfRootView(main);
                    ImageView programLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    programLogo.setImageBitmap(b);



                    File filePath = new File(loadImageFromStorage(saveToInternalStorage(b)), "profile.jpg");


                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.fromParts(
                            "mailto","myemail@gmail.com", null));


                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

                    Uri uri = (Uri) FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, filePath);

                    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/jpg");

                    String subject = "please work";
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Email client :"));
}

});

}

private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage) {
            ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());

            File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            File mypath = new File(directory, "profile.jpg");

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

                bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return directory.getAbsolutePath();
        }

private String loadImageFromStorage(String path) {

            File f = new File(path, "profile.jpg");

            return f.getAbsolutePath();
        }
```

This is the error I get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication234567, PID: 5272
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.example.myapplication234567/app_imageDir/profile.jpg
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:739)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:418)
    at com.example.myapplication234567.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:64)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6913)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6890)
    at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:792)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27158)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:209)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7021)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:486)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:872)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your message contains this path which appears incorrect: /data/data/com.example.myapplication234567/app_imageDir/profile.jpg/profile.jpg

try catches are your friend.

Comment: I realised I was inputting the file name twice due to another section of my code, hence the "/profile.jpg/profile.jpg", however after correcting that the error still appears as "/data/data/com.example.myapplication234567/app_imageDir/profile.jpg" which makes no sense when this path was correct before i implemented the file provider.

Comment: What of the redundant call to 'saveToInternalStorage(b); and then again within your 
                    loadImageFromStorage(saveToInternalStorage(b)); as well as the new file() call.'

Comment: I commented out the first 2 redundant calls and still get the same error message.

Comment: If you would, update your posted code with the loadImageFromStorage() & saveToInternalStorage().

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android development but this is interesting to me. A suggestion for cleaning this up is to change the :<br/> 'loadImageFromStorage()' <br/>to return the file and not the path. Then alter the line 'File filePath = loadImageFromStorage(saveToInternalStorage(b));' No point in having the method load the file to get the path only to load it again.